# StoredProcedureQuery to store image in postgresql Db

Tags: java, image, postgresql, eclipselink

In my application, I am using `StoredProcedureQuery` to call the function to insert data along with an image file. I don't know how set the input parameter for storing the `byte` datatype and how to set the the image file.

Comment: StoredProcedureQuery is not a class in the standard Java. Maybe it is a special wrapper in your project?

Comment: i am using eclipseLink jpa entitymanager to call the postgresql function